# PHP: Sending a request and getting a response

Tags: php

I'm from ASP.NET MVC background and this is first time I'm trying to write something in PHP. 
In ASP.NET MVC we can develop models for our data and using the actions that we write we can get them or send them to another action. What I mean is that

```
public ActionResult Login_Action(LoginModel _Model) {
    // Authenticating the user
    return RedirectToAction(X);
}
```

when calling this the url that is shown in the address bar (in case of using GET, if it is POST nothing will be shown after the page name) will be:

```
www.WebsiteX.com/Login?Username=something&Password=something
```

The problem is that I don't even know how search for this in google (like by typing what exactly) because in Microsoft side, these are handled automatically the way I described. 
But in case of PHP, how can I get the values in the address bar? do I have to get the actual address and then break the values down into arrays?

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: you simply use `$_GET['the variable']`

Comment: Change `Login?Username=something?Password=something` -> `Login?Username=something&Password=something`

Comment: There are some perfect MVC Frameworks for PHP out there too. Consider using Symfony. The MVC model will feel familiar.

Comment: You would start with [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, this seems to be invalid for me: `www.WebsiteX.com/Login?Username=something?Password=something` The first parameter need to be `?` and the others should be `&`.

Second: You can get your values of your parameters by accessing the `$_GET` global array.

Eg. for the username `echo $_GET["Username"];`

Comment: that `?` was typo, sorry, and thank you very much for you crystal clear answer

Comment: @JAX Since you're new to PHP, it doesn't automatically escape output for you so that it's safe to use in HTML ... in this case `echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['Username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')` would be the pedantic way of preventing XSS.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using any framework? You should. And then, the Framework will give you the way to do that. In ASP.NET you use a Framework so do the same in PHP.

With vanille PHP you can get the GET values with $_GET['Username']. But please, use a framework.

I think that the most popular are Laravel and Symfony right now.

Example:
In laravel you can bind a parameter to a variable so you can do something like:

```
//Url: mywebsite.com/user/1/
Route::get('user/{id}', function($id)
{
    return 'User '.$id;
});
```

Which is similar with the ASP.NET example.